# Dealing With jQuery Dependency Within Node Package

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm trying to use a package called 'jvectormap' within Node that has a dependency on jQuery.

http://jvectormap.com/

My question is rather simple. When I try to import `jVectorMap`, I get:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import jVectorMap from 'jvectormap'
```

I've tried importing jQuery as `global.jquery` with no luck. What is the correct protocol with dependencies within Node packages?

Both import just fine, however it seems like jVectorMap can't access jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why packages make jQuery a dependency. good luck

Comment: @meyer9 Ditto...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the package relies on the presence of specific global variables to run. You can try configuring your webpack plugins with the following:

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
```

that will prepend the variables every time it finds a jquery reference.